# Inheriting C++ project properties in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, properties

I have a C++ project in VS2010. I would like another C++ project to inherit its properties (e.g. include directories, external libraries, etc.). It seems the best way to do this is to use Property Sheets, but I can't figure out how to do it.

When I try adding an existing property sheet to my new project, I expect to be able to find a property sheet containing the old project's properties in the old project's directory. No such file exists.

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create inheritable properties you must create a new property sheet, save it in a local location and have any projects you want to have those properties use (inherit) it by "Add Existing" sheet.

The order of the listing of property sheets matters. If the property is listed as "Use default or inherit from parent" it will get the value from the property sheet directly below it or if there is none below it, it will use the default.

The sheets listed in the property sheet manager are just links. If the file is linked to multiple Configurations and you change it in one, ALL linked configurations will accept the changes. Therefore if you want to make different changes for each Config. for the same property you must make separate sheets.