# How to shorten linking process in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, allegro

I'm working with allegro library in Visual Studio C++. And every time I'm creating project I must go through following proccess.

1. Right click your project under Solution Explorer on the right, then 
   select Properties.
2. Under Configuration Properties->C/C++->General, enter
   c:\allegro\include in Additional Include Directories.
3. Under Configuration Properties->Linker->General, enter
   c:\allegro\lib in Additional Library Directories.
4. Under Configuration Properties->Linker->Input, append
   allegro-5.0.x-monolith-md-debug.lib to Additional Dependencies.
5. Under Configuration Properties->Debugging, enter
   PATH=c:\allegro\bin;%PATH% in Environment.
6. Click Apply.

And similarly with Release mode.

I'm using VC for a week so I'm not aware with that sort of stuff and it is really complicated for me.

Is there a way to link this libraries automatically to every project.

Or maybe a better idea is to store this "linking settings" in some kind of build configuration that I can simply apply to solution or project.

Anything that making previously described step by step process shorten or unnecessary would be incredibly helpful.

Sorry for my english I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Property Sheets. This question is very similar to ones I've already answered..several times. So I'll just link them here in chronological order:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10003996/421178

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13734023/421178

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17755536/421178

The last link describes the exact process for creating property sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I think these settings are required for one time when creating a new project. Next time you reload the project, setting up is not required as it is already set.

Alternatively, you can write your own makefiles which will take care of linking and setup PATH variable and use Visual Studio command prompt. You need to write makefile once. Everytime, you call make, it will link with appropriate library.

Comment: Of course I have to set up this only once, but imagine that you'are learning allegro or any other library and you're making a dozen of small projects. Then setting whole thing up  over and over again is very exhausting and annoying.

Comment: Then make an empty project with settings. When you create a new project, copy empty project and make your changes.